Finding the size of a file with C23 embed
If I do:
static char const file[] = {

#embed "this.c"

};

And then:
static char const copy[sizeof file];

I assume sizeof file would be a compile-time constant and would be the actual size of the file. Is that conclusion correct?
(I was unable to get embed to compile with either GCC 13 or Clang 18, so I can't run the code.)

Looking at a draft of the C 2023 standard, #embed operates with an embed element width that may be determined by an implementation-defined parameter and is not necessarily a byte (CHAR_BIT bits). If so, initializing a char array with #embed will lose information and not have the full size of the file. Another problem is if the file has zero length, the #embed token will generate no tokens, and the initialization will be violate a constraint.

By the way, prefer unsigned char over char when working with binary data, to avoid implementation-defined behavior.

It should work given that #embed expands to a valid initialization list.
sizeof expressions are valid integer constant expressions as long as they don't use a VLA operand, as per C23 N3096 6.6:

An integer constant expression shall have integer type and shall only have operands that are... /--/
...sizeof expressions whose results are integer constants, ...

